# Build relative path between two file path

Tags: java, path, relative-path

I would like to compare two paths in the same workspace folder, and get the relative path between them :

```
String firPath = "C:/toto/tata/test1/test2/img/1.jpg" // test example
String secPath = "C:/toto/tata/test1/img/1.jpg" // test example
```

And return firstPath relative path from secondPath

```
example = "../../img/"
```

I found lots of example in different language (python, .net, c++ ...) :

[How to get relative path from absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/how-to-get-relative-path-from-absolute-path)

[compare path and get relative path between two files with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263112/compare-path-and-get-relative-path-between-two-files-with-javascript)

...but no solution with **java**.

Most of the time, what is use are libraries methods, and I was wondering if java had the same methods I could use.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What about added in Java 7 [Path.relativize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize%28java.nio.file.Path%29)?

```
Path first = Paths.get(firstPath); Path second = Paths.get(secondPath);
System.out.println(first.relativize(second)); 
System.out.println(second.relativize(first));
```